# Swagger Try It Out button without actually making changes

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have added Swashbuckle to a new .Net Core Web API to enable Swagger documentation.

Really digging the Try-It-Out option that is provided.

However, is there something in the library that can be checked before calling any underlining business logic?

For example. Take the Try it out on a delete endpoint. I would like to leave the button intact and working, though would not like to actually delete a resource in the event swagger was used to make the call.

Comment: Can you do what you are asking with JavaScript? ... IF you can, you can inject JS using InjectOnCompleteJavaScript: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/98f64b09032c2949e669c319b5cf09ff0f4e2340/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/Application/SwaggerUIOptions.cs#L89

Comment: Do you use [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) or [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore)? And which version?

Comment: @Helen - Using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, v 1.0.0. I could inject javascript to provide a specific header value and watch for that in the controllers, though seems like perhaps a long winded way to do something?

Comment: Just a thought: introduce versioning to your REST api endpoints, and have a version like v1, v2, etc. And include a "version" called "mock", which will point to your mocked API endpoints, where no real data updates, etc. take place.  You really should version your API, in any case.

Comment: @Darren The headers of course! You can use the Headers.Referrer to identify if the request comes from the ***swagger/ui***, watch for that in the controllers and don't actually delete a resource in those cases

Comment: @HelderSepu - yes. I just figured there must be an easier way. I guess I can make an attribute that examines the header and just returns a straightforward OK result rather than executing the action.

Comment: @code4life. Thanks for the idea. We have implemented versioning already.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of leaving the Swagger UI intact, but not the idea of consumers being able to randomly commit any sort of data.

I decided to create a simple `ActionFilterAttribute` that would handle the cases.

The idea, as in my original post, was to allow the button to work, but for some verbs just not actually make changes to any data.

So my resolution is this:

Custom Action Filter Attribute:

```
/// <summary>
/// Simple action filter to prevent executing the action for certain http methods
/// </summary>
public class SwaggerIgnore : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    string[] _ignoreMethods;

    /// <summary>
    /// Ignores the request when coming from Swagger. 
    /// 
    /// Will return a default OK result.
    /// 
    /// Handy if you want to allow the "try" button, but not allow changes to entities; such as HttpDelete
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ignoreMethods">List of methods to ignore; get, delete etc</param>
    public SwaggerIgnore(string[] ignoreMethods)
    {
        _ignoreMethods = ignoreMethods.Select(s => s.ToLower()).ToArray();
    }


    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        string methodExecuting = context.HttpContext.Request.Method.ToLower();
        string referrer = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString().ToLower();
        if (_ignoreMethods.Contains(methodExecuting) && referrer.Contains("swagger"))
            context.Result = new OkResult();
        else
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

And within the `Startup.cs` file, set up as so:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new SwaggerIgnore(new[] { "delete", "post", "put" }));
    });
```

So now, when running any delete, post or put from the swagger page no data is actually handled, but the actions return an OK.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative will be to use an `AuthorizeAttribute` that allows a bit more flexibility, just in case we want to allow some but not others.

```
public class IgnoreSwaggerUiRequestAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext a)
    {
        bool methodNotAllowed = false;
        try
        {
            methodNotAllowed = a.Request.Headers.Referrer.AbsoluteUri.Contains("swagger/ui");
        }
        catch { }
        if (methodNotAllowed)
        {
            a.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed,
                Content = new StringContent("This method is not allowed from the swagger ui")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And then we decorate those methods that we do not want to show any data like this:

```
    [IgnoreSwaggerUiRequest]
    public string Delete(int id)
```